# Boost threads running serially, not in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, boost-thread

I'm a complete newbie to multi-threading in C++, and decided to start with the Boost Libraries. Also, I'm using Intel's C++ Compiler (from Parallel Studio 2011) with VS2010 on Vista.

I'm coding a genetic algorithm, and want to exploit the benefits of multi-threading: I want to create a thread for each individual (object) in the population, in order for them to calculate their fitness (heavy operations) in parallel, to reduce total execution time.

As I understand it, whenever I launch a child thread it stars working "in the background", and the parent thread continues to execute the next instruction, right? So, I thought of creating and launching all the child threads I need (in a `for` loop), and then wait for them to finish (call each thread's `join()` in another `for` loop) before continuing.

The problem I'm facing is that the first loop won't continue to the next iteration until the newly created thread is done working. Then, the second loop is as good as gone, since all the threads are already joined by the time that loop is hit.

Here are (what I consider to be) the relevant code snippets. Tell me if there is anything else you need to know.

```
class Poblacion {
    // Constructors, destructor and other members
    // ...
    list<Individuo> _individuos;
    void generaInicial() { // This method sets up the initial population.
        int i;
        // First loop
        for(i = 0; i < _tamano_total; i++) {
            Individuo nuevo(true);
            nuevo.Start(); // Create and launch new thread
            _individuos.push_back(nuevo);
        }

        // Second loop
        list<Individuo>::iterator it;
        for(it = _individuos.begin(); it != _individuos.end(); it++) {
            it->Join();
        }

        _individuos.sort();
    }
};
```

And, the threaded object *Individuo*:

```
class Individuo {
    private:
        // Other private members
        // ...
        boost::thread _hilo;

    public:
        // Other public members
        // ...
        void Start() {
            _hilo = boost::thread(&Individuo::Run, this);
        }
        void Run() {
            // These methods operate with/on each instance's own attributes,
            // so they *can't* be static
            generaHoc();
            calculaAptitud();
            borraArchivos();
        }
        void Join() {
            if(_hilo.joinable()) _hilo.join();
        }
};
```

Thank you! `:D`

Comment: It's interesting to do such thing with Boost.threads, but OpenMP will make it much easier

Comment: @CharlesB I think that for this particular case, the problems are solved, but I'll look into OpenMP. Thank's for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's your real code then you have a problem.

```
    for(i = 0; i < _tamano_total; i++) {
        Individuo nuevo(true);
        nuevo.Start(); // Create and launch new thread
        _individuos.push_back(nuevo);
    }

    void Start() {
        _hilo = boost::thread(&Individuo::Run, this);
    }
```

This code creates a new `Individuo` object on the stack, then starts a thread that runs, passing the `this`pointer of that stack object to the new thread. It then **copies** that object into the `list`, and **promptly destroys the stack object, leaving a dangling pointer in the new thread**. This gives you undefined behaviour.

Since `list` never moves an object in memory once it has been inserted, you could start the thread **after** inserting into the list:

```
    for(i = 0; i < _tamano_total; i++) {
        _individuos.push_back(Individuo(true)); // add new entry to list
        _individuos.back().Start(); // start a thread for that entry
    }
```

Comment: Yes! That was exactly the problem. I was sure it had something to do with `list.push_back()` copying the object (since I had to overload the copy ctor but couldn't really seize the issue - I tried using a pointer-to-thread instead of thread but it only arose some strange reference count errors). But I digress... Thank you very much!